# "Difference in behavior when injecting JavaScript code into frames using 'allFrames: true' vs 'frameIds: []' in amazon.DE vs amazon.COM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, frames

My extension is supposed to inject js-code to scrape the active tab for images when the popup is opened.

I encountered a problem in amazon.DE where the JS-code breaks at the point of script injection, but not amazon.COM! No codes after the injection get's executed and I get no error message in the consoles of both my popup nor the active Tab.

I think the issue comes down to the code being injected into all [frames][edit], not all of which share their host with the active tab.

From my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,

    "permissions": [
      "storage",
      "unlimitedStorage",
      "activeTab",
      "scripting",
      "webNavigation"
    ]
}
```

The code I use for injection:

```
async scrape() {
    let tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true });
    let tab = tabs[0];

    let frames = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target:{tabId: tab.id, allFrames: true},
      func:grabImages
    });
```

My bug testing has yielded the following:

- the script always gets injected in the frames I care about (main frames). It can do what I want it to do there.
- if the script injects via `allFrames: true` into amazon.COM I don't have an issue
- if the script injects via `frameIds: [list, of, ids, of, all, frames]` it breaks with the error message:
  `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.`
- if the script injects via `allFrames:true` into amazon.DE it breaks without any error message
- the code works fine on the amazon.DE homepage, it only fails on the product pages
- if I click my extension fast enough, before the product page of amazon is fully loaded it works (kinda, it is missing some images that are present on the fully loaded page)
- the amazon.COM product page has 3 frames, the amazon.DE frames has 7.

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between injecting via `allFrames: true` vs injecting via `frameIds: []` that leads to the difference in outcome?
2. Why does "allFrames: true" work on amazon.COM but fails silently on amazon.DE?

Comment: Definitely a bug in Chrome, but do you really need to inject in iframes on amazon? They aren't even visible here. Anyway, try using webNavigation.getAllFrames and then check the URL to inject only in those iframes that might contain images. Apparently the bug is triggered by some weird iframe e.g. sandbox or something injected by another extension.

Comment: I'm talking about frames, not iframes (had one misstype that I fixed now, sorry for that). My thought was that old pages might still have images in multiple frames. And I would like the extension to work on old webpages as well.

Comment: A frame is created via iframe tag in modern web so the practical meaning is the same. It's used both by "old pages" and "new pages".

Comment: Huh, thanks for that Info! Are iframes the only way a website might have created a frame?

Comment: One ancient way is `frameset` + `frame`. There may others that I'm not aware of, but none of these is used by popular modern web sites. As for getAllFrames, it probably can also return the prerendered main frame (look at its `documentLifecycle` property), which is still hidden while awaiting actual user navigation in this tab, as well as bfcache'd main frame.